# Retrieve x64 Program Files path from 32-bit process

Tags: c#, wix, 64-bit

First some background. I have created a WPF bootstrapper application for my WiX installer where I need to retrieve and display the default install location. Unless I am doing something wrong it appears the executable created by WiX is always 32-bit even if my Visual Studio configuration is set to x64 and this leads to my problem.

Since the executable is always 32-bit the library containing my WPF bootstrapper application is also loaded as 32-bit even when I want to install my x64 MSI-file. So when I try to retrieve the default installation path using `Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.ProgramFiles)` I get *C:\Program Files (x86)* instead of *C:\Program Files*. How would I go about retrieving *C:\Program Files* from a 32-bit process when running on 64-bit OS?

I have found similar questions but I have not found an adequate answer, I want a solution that works even if the OS language is not English. I was thinking about removing " (x86)" from the retrieved path but it seems hacky and I am not sure if it will work in all situations.

Comment: `Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("ProgramW6432");`

Comment: @codroipo you may want to expand your comment into a full answer!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If OS is 64 bit and your application is 32 bit you can get *Program Files* folder using an environment variable (actually there is a special - unsupported in `Environment.SpecialFolder` - constant in `SHGetSpecialFolderLocation` but it's easier like this):

```
Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("ProgramW6432");
```

Just check your OS is 64 bit (in 32 bit systems this variable isn't defined):

```
if (Environment.Is64BitOperatingSystem && !Environment.Is64BitProcess)
    return Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("ProgramW6432");
else
    return Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.ProgramFiles);
```

Comment: Looking up "ProgramW6432" is in fact not a catch-all solution. As stated [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa384274%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) the "W6432" environment variables (there is more than one) only exist in Windows 7, Windows Server 2008 R2 and later. This means that Windows Vista, Windows Server 2008, Windows XP and Windows Server 2003 are not covered. One could argue that those operating systems are either unsupported or shortly will be, but that's beside the point.